Assigning Clone Button on Lightning Related List
The attached screenshot shows a Skills list that is related to Participants with a Lookup(Participants) relationship. Notice Dropdown next to each item in the list allows Edit or Delete. I would like to add Clone but I cannot find where I can make that setting.
Clone is a standard button that is selected in the Skills pageview and appears elsewhere, such as at the top of the page in the attachment - but there it relates to cloning the parent Participant record.
TIA!

